# Send Outlook task on value change

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Mail is sent when the value in a cell of a specific row changes.

In addition we now want to send an Outlook task whenever that happens. The following first part is the email.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, strbody As String
    If Target.Column = 44 Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        strbody = "Text "
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Sheets("Param").Cells(3, 4)
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Text"
            .Body = strbody
            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Until here the code works. I've added the part about the task and although the code works without the IF THEN statement I can't get it to trigger with it or I get a 424 error.

```
Private Sub SendTask()
    Dim objOut As Outlook.Application
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Dim blnCrt As Boolean
    If Target.Column = 6 Then 'modification numéro agrément
        On Error GoTo CreateOutlook
        Set objOut = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
CreateItem:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set objTask = objOut.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
        With objTask
            .Assign
            .Subject = "You need to fix this!"
            .Body = "Please fix this problem by " & Format(Now + 10, "mm/dd/yy")
            .DueDate = CDate(Now + 10)
            .Recipients.Add ("youremail@domain.com")
            .Display
        End With
        If blnCrt = True Then objOut.Quit
        Set objTask = Nothing
        Set objOut = Nothing
        Exit Sub
CreateOutlook:
        Set objOut = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        blnCrt = True
        Resume CreateItem
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `If... Then` line you're referring to is the first one - `If Target.Column...`.

Comment: You can't say whether the first part of your code "`works without an issue`", since you're using `On Error Resume Next` which means *"If there are errors, I don't even want to know about them"*.  It is not a good idea to use `Resume Next` at all, and even moreso while trying to troubleshoot a problem.

Comment: Yes exactly I forgot there's a second IF statement in the second part

Comment: @ ashleedawg We've been using the first part without an issue so far, even when using the second part as a standalone it doesn't want to work. But you're right in this case it doesn't help my troubleshooting

Comment: You wouldn't know even if there **is** an issue - possibly one affecting something else (as unknown factors usually do).  Anyhow, if it's running fine, it won't change anything to comment-out or remove the `On Error` line anyhow...

Comment: Read up on the [Worksheet Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change). `Target` is the changed range and can be more than one cell. Modify your existing `Worksheet_Change` code. `Target` within `SendTask` is an undeclared `Variant`.

Comment: Also, where does SendTask get the value of Target.Column? Is it a global object variable that you declared?  I suggest you add the line `Option Explicit` to the very top of the module and try running the code again. It helps ensure that you are properly declaring and referring to your variables/objects/etc

Comment: @ashleedawg @BigBen  The issue was as pointed out the fact that `target` was undeclared. I've modified the code and added them to the same sub. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

New version of the code that seems to work as intended

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String


If target.Column = 6 Then 'Modification of value in row 6
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)



    With OutMail
     .Assign
     .Subject = "You need to fix this!"
     .Body = "Please fix this problem by " & Format(Now + 10, "mm/dd/yy")
     .DueDate = CDate(Now + 10)
     .Recipients.Add ("youremail@domain.com")
     .Display
    End With


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Den numèro d'agrément "


    With OutMail
        .To = Sheets("Param").Cells(3, 4)
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Fichier acquéreur: modification numéro agrément"
        .Body = strbody
        .Display   
    End With


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: While [users are encouraged to answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), an answer should consist of more than just code.  Ideally an explanation of why the solution works, and related link(s) if possible are  likely to help others who may run in to the same issue (and more likely to earn upvotes!)  (See [answer].)